# MvxCommand binding changing layout screens

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

So in my project I am using MvvXCross and PCL for my Xamarin.Droid project.

So I have a login screen that needs to call the PCL and the PCL will call a service to see if a user is authenticated based on a bool value.

I have hooked up my Layout button to my LoginViewModel and I have added a MvxCommand as well to send the user to another page.

The problem comes in that the ICommand gets loaded when the Login Layout gets loaded so I can't but my authentication on the user there.

How would I be able to create a Command that will first call a method and evaluate it and depending on the evaluation would send the user to another layout or make the user stay on the same layout with a error message?

I have provided some code of my viewmodel and layout for login.

LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly ILoginService _loginService;
    public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
    }

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
    }

    //User's username
    private string _username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username); }
    }

    //User's password
    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password); }
    }

    public string AuthenticateUser()
    {

        return null;
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<HomeViewModel> ());
        }
    }
}
```

My Login Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/synchramed_trans_300"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_top_bg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColorHint="#ADA6A6"
            style="@style/DefaultTextBox"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColorHint="#ADA6A6"
            android:password="true"
            style="@style/DefaultTextBox"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <CheckBox
                android:text="Remember Me?"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSingIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            style="@style/DefaultButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_default_bg"
            local:MvxBind="Click LoginCommand" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your LoginService.Authenticate() method in LoginCommand. If the authentication is successful, then you can navigate to the next screen, otherwise display an error.

Here's how I currently do it.

```c#
private MvxCommand _signinCommand;
public ICommand SigninCommand
{
    get
    {
        _signinCommand = _signinCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoSignin);
        return _signinCommand;
    }
}


private async void DoSignin()
{
    try
    {
        if (!Validate())
        {
            return;
        }

        IsBusy = true;
        var success = await SigninService.SigninAsync(Email, Password);

        if (success)
        {
            Result = "";
            ShowViewModel<HomeViewModel>();
            Close();
            return;
        }

        Result = "Invalid email/password. Please try again.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Result = "Error occured during sign in.";
        Mvx.Error(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Added layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mainlogo" />
    <EditText
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        local:MvxBind="Text Email; Error Errors['Email']"
        android:id="@+id/EmailEditText" />
    <EditText
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        local:MvxBind="Text Password; Error Errors['Password']"
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText" />
    <TextView
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="Result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ResultTextView"
        local:MvxBind="Text Result; Visibility HasResult,Converter=Visibility"
        android:textColor="#f00" />
    <Button
        android:height="48dp"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Click SigninCommand;Enabled IsBusy,Converter=Inverted"
        android:id="@+id/SigninButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted to ask - The Close method accepts an argument of ViewModel, what viewmodel should be there. And secondly The "Result" how does this get sent back to the layout to be displayed?

Comment: Result is simply a property bound to a TextView (see layout). As for Close(), that was a custom extension method. You should just use Close(this).